# Help me use powershell and bcp to load CSV into SQL Server

Tags: powershell, bcp, powershell-1.0

I'm using bcp to load a table from a CSV exported from another table by someone else far far away, and have run into some issues. My original two problems: one exported field is an int that needs to end up in a varchar field, and another field needs to be populated with a static string. Well, the first is no big deal, and Chad's answer led me to the `@{n='Col3';e={'ABC'}}` syntax. But i'm stumbling around several issues getting the data loaded correctly.

1. Sometimes a value might have no spaces, sometimes it might. How do i specify delimiters for that in a bcp format file? I ask because presumably i need to surround these with quotes.

   a. Should i be wrapping values in the intermediate CSV file with quotes?
2. In my test code, it's shoving the column headers and a linefeed into Col1 with the actual value of Col1 for the first row.
3. In my actual, unsanitized code, i'm getting `String data, right truncation` on the first row, though the second row is inserted okay.

Anyhow, the initial CSV data that i get from elsewhere looks like this (note: no header row)

```
"ABC123",123456,"APPLE"
"XYZ789",456789,"ORANGE"
```

The target SQL table is like this

```
Col1 varchar(50) (Primary Key)
Col2 varchar(50)
Col3 varchar(50)
Col4 varchar(50)
```

I need to load *ABC123* into `Col1`, *123456* into `Col2`, *Export1* into `Col3`, and *APPLE* into `Col4`. *Export1* is the static string. I'm doing this in Powershell 1.0.

EDIT: Chad's import-csv | export-csv looks promising, but it doesn't like missing headers, and PS 1.0 doesn't support the -Header option.

EDIT: Edited description above to reflect how i've wandered to this point. The four-column table and three-column CSV are obviously simplifications. One real column is a city, so it could contain simple strings or those that require quoting. My Powershell 1.0 code at this point is as follows.

```
$SQLSERVER="svr"
$SQLTABLE="test"
$SQLUSER="u"
$SQLPASS="p"

$TESTFILE = "testdata.csv"
$TESTFILEHDR = "testdata-wHeaders.csv"
$TESTFILEFIX = "testdata-fixed.csv"
$OrigHeaders = "`"Col1`",`"Col2`",`"Col3`"`n"

function Create-BcpFormat($fileName)
{
@"
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <RECORD>
  <FIELD ID='1' xsi:type='CharTerm' TERMINATOR=',"' COLLATION='SQL_AltDiction_CP850_CI_AS'/>
  <FIELD ID='2' xsi:type='CharTerm' TERMINATOR='",' COLLATION='SQL_AltDiction_CP850_CI_AS'/>
  <FIELD ID='3' xsi:type='CharTerm' TERMINATOR=',' COLLATION='SQL_AltDiction_CP850_CI_AS'/>
  <FIELD ID='4' xsi:type='CharTerm' TERMINATOR='\r\n' COLLATION='SQL_AltDiction_CP850_CI_AS'/>
 </RECORD>
 <ROW>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="Col1" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="Col2" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="3" NAME="Col3" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="4" NAME="Col4" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
 </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
"@ | Set-Content $filename
}

## GHI456 is already in the table, clean out previous attempts
"`nclean test table:"
osql @("-S","$SQLSERVER","-U","$SQLUSER","-P","$SQLPASS","-Q",
    """delete from $SQLTABLE where col1 <> 'GHI456' or col1 is null""")

## Prepend
$body = [string]::join([environment]::NewLine, (gc $TESTFILE))
$OrigHeaders + $body > $TESTFILEHDR

"`nTESTFILEHDR:"
type $TESTFILEHDR

$accts = Import-csv $TESTFILEHDR | select 'Col1', 'Col2', @{n='Col3';e={'ABC'}}, @{n='Col4';e={$_.Col3}}
$accts
$accts | Export-Csv $TESTFILEFIX -NoTypeInfo

"`nTESTFILEFIX:"
type $TESTFILEFIX

$BCPFMTFILE = "bcp.fmt"
$BCPERRFILE = "bcp.err"
Create-BcpFormat $BCPFMTFILE
bcp @("$SQLTABLE","in","$TESTFILEFIX","-S","$SQLSERVER","-U","$SQLUSER","-P","$SQLPASS","-f",$BCPFMTFILE,"-e",$BCPERRFILE)
Remove-Item $BCPFMTFILE

"`ntest table:"
osql @("-S","$SQLSERVER","-U","$SQLUSER","-P","$SQLPASS","-Q",
    """select left(Col1,20) 'Col1', left(Col2,8) 'Col2', left(Col3,8) 'Col3', left(Col4,8) 'Col4' from $SQLTABLE""")

"`nBCPERRFILE:"
type $BCPERRFILE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use ADO.NET's SqlBulkCopy programmatically in PowerShell?
You will have full control: read line by line, convert data and populate a DataTable as you wish and invoke WriteToServer in batches.
See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx

Comment: thanks. This got me closest to the answer. I ended up building a *sqlcmd* file with inserts in powershell, but you got me out of thinking *bcp* was the answer. Bulk copy was claiming i don't have permission. Anyhow, even though sqlcmd is working, i plan on tinkering with an ADO.NET solution. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped
Here's an example how to create necessary objects

if ($global:systemDataAssembly -eq $null)
{
    [Reflection.Assembly]$global:systemDataAssembly = [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Data");
}

[System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy]$local:bulkCopy = New-Object -TypeName "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy" -ArgumentList "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=yes;Initial Catalog=test";

$local:bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.test";

[System.Data.DataTable]$local:dataTable = New-Object -TypeName "System.Data.DataTable";
# here goes real action

Comment: sorry, formatting went wrong. Haven't mastered it yet. It seems to work differently in comments.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this to add the column

import-csv .\forum.csv -Header "Col1","Col2","Col4" | Select Col1, Col2, @{n='Col3';e={'Export1'}}, Col4 | Export-Csv ./forum2.csv -NoTypeInfo

Comment: do you mean create an intermediate CSV and then bcp **that** into SQL?

Comment: If you want to update the original csv file use this:

(import-csv .\forum.csv -Header "Col1","Col2","Col4") | Select Col1, Col2, @{n='Col3';e={'Export1'}}, Col4 | Export-Csv ./forum.csv -NoTypeInfo

Comment: this was helpful, so +1, but it didn't get me there. The answer was appreciated though!