# Output Value to SQL Server

Tags: html, sql-server, powershell, csv, database-design

I am having trouble getting my results (screenshot below) to output into my database (Hal0Test). From my research online I found some snippets of code but I am not too sure about the "declare" in respect to my code. ALSO, the HTML output is just for me to see the results without having to open SQL managment everytime and refreshing. My end goal is to get all the server infromation to my database, Hal0Test.

**Issues:**

1. HTML talbe will only show the last server in the list but when debugging and in console it will show the result of all my servers.
2. SQL Server Table (ServerList) is not changing at all from the below powershell script.

**New Code with HTML:**

```
Write-Output " `n Start of Hal0 `n";

#Start of Server Connection
$connectionString = "Server=QAUTILITYDB01;Database=Hal0Test;Integrated Security=True;"
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString
$connection.Open()
$command = $connection.CreateCommand()

$ServerArray = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
$query = "SELECT ServerName FROM ServerList"
$command.CommandText = $query
$ServerNames = $command.ExecuteReader()

$table = new-object “System.Data.DataTable”
$table.Load($ServerNames)

$ServerArray = $table | select -Expand ServerName

#Variables for each Server in Array
$ServerArray | ForEach-Object {
    # $ServerArray returns each server name

    #Operating System
    $os    = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Computer $_ 
    #Server's Memory (RAM) Usage Average
    $memAvg    = gwmi -Class win32_operatingsystem -computername $_ | 
    Select-Object @{Name = "MemoryUsage"; Expression = {“{0:N2}” -f ((($_.TotalVisibleMemorySize - $_.FreePhysicalMemory)*100)/ $_.TotalVisibleMemorySize) }} 
    #Server's CPU (Proccess) Usage Average
    $cpuAVG = Get-WmiObject -computername $_ win32_processor |  
    Measure-Object -property LoadPercentage -Average | Select Average 
    #Server's Hard Drives (MB) Free/Used
    $disks = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -Computer $_ |
             Where-Object {$_.DriveType -eq 3} |
             ForEach-Object {
                 '{0} {1:D} MB Free/{2:D} MB Used' -f $_.DeviceID,
                     [int]($_.FreeSpace/1MB), [int]($_.Size/1MB)
             }


    New-Object -Type PSCustomObject -Property @{
      'FQDN' = $_
      'ServerName' = $os.PSComputerName
      'OperatingSystem' = $os.Caption
      'CPUAvg' = "$($cpuAVG.Average)%"
      'MemAvg' = "$($memAvg.MemoryUsage)%"
      'Disks'  = $disks -join ' | '
    }

    $command.CommandText = "UPDATE ServerList SET FQDN = '$_', OS = '$os.Caption' WHERE ServerName = '$os.PSComputerName';"
    $result = $command.ExecuteNonQuery()

    $Outputreport = "<HTML><TITLE> IDI Server Report </TITLE>
                    <BODY background-color:peachpuff> 
                     <font color =""#99000"" face=""Microsoft Tai le""> 
                     <H2> IDI Server Report </H2></font> 
                     <Table border=1 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0> 
                     <TR bgcolor=gray align=center> 
                       <TD><B>Server Name</B></TD> 
                       <TD><B>FQDN</B></TD>
                       <TD><B>CPU Usage</B></TD> 
                       <TD><B>RAM Usage</B></TD> 
                       <TD><B>Disk Space</B></TD> 
                       <TD><B>Operating System</B></TD></TR>" 

    Foreach($Entry in $ServerArray)  
        {  
          if(($Entry.CPUAvg) -ge "2")  
          {  
            $Outputreport += "<TR bgcolor=#FF0000>"  
          }  
          else 
           { 
            $Outputreport += "<TR bgcolor=#E6E6FA>"  
          } 
          $Outputreport += "<TD>$($os.PSComputerName)</TD>
                                           <TD align=center>$($_)</TD>
                                           <TD align=center>$("$($cpuAVG.Average)%")</TD>
                                           <TD align=center>$("$($memAvg.MemoryUsage)%")</TD>
                                           <TD align=center>$($disks)</TD><TD align=center>$($os.Caption)</TD>
                                           </TR>"  
        } 
     $Outputreport += "</Table></BODY></HTML>"  
        } 

    $Outputreport | out-file C:\Users\king\Desktop\HalO\ServerReport.html
    Invoke-Expression C:\Users\king\Desktop\HalO\ServerReport.html

Write-Output "`n End of Hal0";
```

HTML Results:

[image]

Comment: Your "CSV" is opened in Excel? Excel assumes comma delimiters unless you use the text import wizard and specify an alternate delimiter like the pipe. I would also consider using a different inner delimiter for Disks

Comment: Why not use SqlBulkCopy or BCP in PowerShell? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526368/help-me-use-powershell-and-bcp-to-load-csv-into-sql-server

Comment: I think SqlBulkCopy is a bit too complex for my simple needs of pushing just 4 values for 5 servers into a single database. @lucazav

Answer (score 1):

Check the value of `$command.CommandText` - I bet it's not what you think it is.

When you use object properties inside a string, you need to wrap it in `$()`. So this"

```
$command.CommandText = "UPDATE ServerList SET FQDN = '$_', OS = '$os.Caption' WHERE ServerName = '$os.PSComputerName';"
```

Becomes this:

```
$command.CommandText = "UPDATE ServerList SET FQDN = '$_', OS = '$($os.Caption)' WHERE ServerName = '$($os.PSComputerName)';"
```

Or, you could use a `PreparedStatement` and set your values as parameters, eliminating that string manipulation (and preventing an unexpected single quote from ruining your day).

But I think the problem goes deeper than that. The values in `$ServerArray` aren't FQDNs, but in your `Foreach-Object` loop that's how you're treating them. Inside that loop, `$_` is the value you retrieved from the `ServerName` field on `ServerList` - so the `WHERE` clause of your `UPDATE` query is finding nothing.

In your loop, to get the FQDN, use `Get-ADComputer`:

```
get-adcomputer $_|Select-Object -ExpandProperty dnshostname
```

You'll also need to store this somewhere to put it into your `UPDATE` statement.

```
$FQDN = get-adcomputer $_|Select-Object -ExpandProperty dnshostname;
$command.CommandText = "UPDATE ServerList SET FQDN = '$FQDN', OS = '$($os.Caption)' WHERE ServerName = '$_';"
```

The explanation for why Excel isn't opening the file as you expected was already given - when you double-click a CSV file, Excel assumes that it's comma-delimited. You need to do a File->Open and step through the wizard to tell it what your delimiter is.

I'd really like to take a crack at revamping the whole script here for you, but am short on time at the moment.

Comment: Thank you very much @alroc. So I decided to remove the whole csv altogether and just have an html output just so I can see what my results are. However, does your answer change with my new code?

Comment: Whenever you get a chance @alroc a revamp would be GREAT. The new code uses html instead of a csv so that will hopefully make things easier. Let me know if u need anything from my end!

Comment: HTML is fine for output if that's your true requirement for output. I prefer to store things to CSV or a database so that it's more easily used for future processing.

Comment: The HTML page is just used for me locally to see what is getting pushed to the server. However, I can not figure out this issue with all the tables having the same server 08 instead of 01,03,05,06,and 08. Which is proabably why my database is not getting any updates.